# ¿Como comparar cada valor de dos arrays entre ellas en python?

Tags: python, array, vectores

Holaa! El dia de hoy necesito saber como comparar cada valor de dos array y si una de esas arrays tiene algunos de los valores de la otra termine el ciclo. porfa necesito ayuda, el ciclo me queda infinito.

**CODE**

```
hola = True
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
array2 = [20,60,1,2,40,80,3,4,5,6,7,9,100,8]

while hola == True:
   print("¿Como estas?")
   if array1 == array2 or array2 == array1:
     hola = False
```

Así esta mi codigo y lo que pido es que: Si el **array1** contiene algunos valores que contenga tambien el **array2**, el programa pare, en este caso quiero el programa pare porque el **array2** tiene todos los valores del **array1** en diferente orden, pero los tiene entonces deberia parar

Comment: `if any((n in array2 for n in array1))`: break

Answer (score 2):

La comprensión de lista

```
[x for x in lista1 if x in lista2]
```

genera una lista con todos los elementos de `lista1` que están en `lista2`. Con eso el problema se reduce a ver si la lista tiene elementos o no.

Para facilitar las cosas hare una función que me retorna una lista con los elementos de la primera que están en la segunda:

```
def sublista(lista1, lista2):
    return [x for x in lista1 if x in lista2]
```

Recordemos que en Python una lista vacía es `False` y cualquier otra es `True`.

#### Demo

```
def sublista(lista1, lista2):
    return [x for x in lista1 if x in lista2]

array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
array2 = [20,60,1,2,40,80,3,4,5,6,7,9,100,8]
array3 = [-1]


if sublista(array1, array2):
    print("array1 en array2")
if sublista(array2, array1):
    print("array2 en array1")
if sublista(array1, array3):
    print("array1 en array3")
```

produce:

```
array1 en array2
array2 en array1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Buena respuesta! Muy pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tiene tu codigo es que no estás indexando correctamente las listas, al hacer `array1 == array2` estás comparando las variables que contienen las listas por referencia y no por sus elementos individualmente.

Para lograr lo que necesitas necesitas iterar sobre los elementos de uno de los dos arreglos, y podemos aprovechar la expresión de Python `in` para evaluar si aquel elemento se encuentra en el otro.

Si al terminar de iterar el primer arreglo no se encontraron coincidencias el ciclo termina naturalmente.

```py
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
array2 = [20,60,1,2,40,80,3,4,5,6,7,9,100,8]

for element in array1:
  if element in array2:
    print(f"el elemento {element} está repetido!")
    break
```

Comment: otra forma sería convertir a set y encontrar la intersección, si hay intersección es porque algunos o todos los elementos de `array1` se encuentran en `array2`, por ejemplo `if set(array1)&set(array2): print("hay coincidencias")`